# dictionary of dictionary - How to update or create a value if key does not exist yet?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code to add or update, if already exists, a `dict()`-value in a `dict`:

```
if id not in self.steps:
    self.steps[ id ] = step
else:
    self.steps[ id ].update(step)
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering whether I can simplify the code. I tried using `get`, but get seems to return a copy of the element (or simply a new element, not associated to the missing key?) if key does not exists.

```
self.steps.get( id ).update(step)
```

What are my options?

Comment: 3 downvotes? Common guys, what's up? Have mercy and explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) , with the inner values as dict. Example -

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> d1 = {1:2,3:4}
>>> d['id1'].update(d1)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'id1': {1: 2, 3: 4}})
```

Comment: Much clearer to use `defaultdict` than `setdefault()` (which is a get in reality). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
d={}
d.setdefault(i,0)
d[i]=somevalue
```

You can use `setdefault` to remove `if else` condition.

[More info here](http://starship.python.net/crew/mwh/hacks/setdefault.html)

Comment: So in my case I would do `d.setdefault(i, {})` ?

Comment: Now i got it, `setdefault` replaces my `get`. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind, please update your answer to show that `get` should be `setdefault` to do what I want. 

It's not straight forward to guess that `setdefault` does a `get` with creating the element which didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet will update the value if the key already exists, if not it will initialize will value 0 for eg.

```
result = {}
if true:
    result['key'] = result.get('key', 0) + 1
```